# Why is xinit making my physical display blank?

Tags: debian, x11, nvidia

I have been trying to get remote openGL working for my debian 8 machine.

I read around that  `sudo xinit &` lets you run it (and it works. after i do it , im able to to , though I suspect its not using my server's gpu)

I have an nvidia card installed.

Help is appreciated , been at it for a long time :( 
This is my xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.20  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06)  Tue Nov 15 17:49:44 PST 2016
Section "DRI"
    Mode 0660
    Group "vglusers"
EndSection


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1050 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "None"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Virtual     1280 1024
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```